# Custom type Enum extended from ChoiceType. Symfony

Tags: symfony, enums, formbuilder

In the type for the form, the custom type "enum" is used. When I select a value in the form selection and save it, when I reopen the form in the selection, this value does NOT come first. For example, if I chose "secondary" saved and opened the form again, then in the selection in the first place it will still be "primary". How to put the value of the instance in the first place in select?

```
 /**
 * Class SomethingType
 *
 * @method static SomethingType PRIMARY()
 * @method static SomethingType SECONDARY()
 */
final class SomethingType extends AbstractEnum
{
    const PRIMARY = 'primary';
    const SECONDARY = 'secondary';
}
```

In custom type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', 'enum', [
            'class' => 'SomethingType',
        ]);
}
```

enum:

```
class EnumType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->resetViewTransformers()
            ->addModelTransformer(new EnumTransformer($options['class']));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver Validates options and merges them with
     *                                  default values.
     * @return void
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefined('class')
            ->setDefault('choices', function (Options $options) {
                $data = [];
                if (isset($options['class'])) {
                    $enum = call_user_func($options['class'] . '::values');
                    /** @var AbstractEnum $item */
                    foreach ($enum as $item) {
                        $value = $item->getValue();
                        $data[$value] = $value;
                    }
                }
                return $data;
            });
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'enum';
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your Symfony version? A form type as string (not FQCN) is deprecated some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your should create custom twig template:

```
{% block enum_widget %}
    {% if form is defined %}
        {% if instanceof(form.vars.value, 'AbstractEnum')  %}
            {% spaceless %}
                {%- set currentValue = form.vars.value.getValue -%}
                <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
                    {%- set options = choices -%}
                    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
                        <option value="{{ choice.value }}"
                                {% if choice.attr %}{% with { attr: choice.attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}
                                {% if choice.value == currentValue %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                            {{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            {% endspaceless %}
        {% else %}
            {{ block('choice_widget') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```